# Differential equation with interpolation

Tags: differential-equations

If I have a second-order nonlinear differential equation as follow:

```
sol = NDSolve[{*w''[z] - G[z]*w[z] == 0,  w'[0] == 100, w[L] == 0.001}, w[z], z]
```

where:

`G[z]` is local values change with `z` or it could be an interpolation.
Is there any method to solve the equation if `G[z]` is considered interpolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> G[z] is local values change with z or it could be an interpolation
>    Is there any method to solve the equation if G[z] is considered
>   interpolation.

It will be better to give more details and example, so one does not have to guess how things defined.

But interpolation functions works the same way as any other function. So as long as the range of data of your `G` is within the domain of the ODE it should work as is

```
ClearAll[z, G, w];
G = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the domain is from 1 to 6.

```
L = 6;
sol = NDSolve[{w''[z] - G[z]*w[z] == 0, w'[1] == 100, w[L] == 0.001}, w[z], {z, 1, L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Evaluate[w[z] /. sol], {z, 1, L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you give the domain for ODE outside the interpolation function domain, you'll get warnings from `NDSolve` but it will still work, but result might not be as accurate

```
ClearAll[z, G, w];
G = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}]
L = 10;
sol = NDSolve[{w''[z] - G[z]*w[z] == 0, w'[0] == 100, w[L] == 0.001}, w[z], {z, 0, L}]
```

Warning

```
 InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.} lies outside the range of 
 data in the  interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

Now

```
Plot[Evaluate[w[z] /. sol], {z, 0, L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @MohammadSAl-tawaha Doesn't Nasser's code work with your `G`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am sorry. It works very well

Comment: Thank you so much, Nasser. I appreciate what you have answered